# R code: i got NA as result when i am calling my functon

Tags: r

When I call my function it show NA?
 Although, when I'm sending different parameters it works. So my question how many results should be one or two for each call and why sometimes i got NA.

Here is my code:

```
trsp<-function(x,p,tr,mlo,mhi)
 {
  mm<-seq(mlo, mhi, length =101)
  w<-double(length (mm))
  for (k in 1:101)
  {
    xmm<-sort(abs((x-mm[k]))^p)
    w[k]<-sum(xmm[c(1:ceiling(tr*length(x)))])
  }
  mmw<-cbind(mm, w)
  plot(mmw)
  mmw[w<-min(w)]
 }  

dta<-rcauchy(23)

trsp(dta,1,1,0,1)
trsp(dta,2,1,0,1)
trsp(dta,1,0.6,0,1)
trsp(dta,2,0.6,0,1)
trsp(dta,0.5,0.6,0,1)
```

Comment: The second argument is 2 for the case when I get NA. All the other calls have the "p" value less than 1. Does that make any sense for whatever uncommented algorithm you are implementing? (It is generally more helpful to actually describe _what_ you are attempting if you ask for help.)

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this question step by step.

1) how many results should be one or two for each call?: Well, it will display only ONE result for each call. The reason being the fact that when we cbind two vectors, we get a matrix as output. In a matrix, if we use one subscript instead of two, the output is similar to what you would have got after casting a matrix to a vector and accessing an element of the vector.

2) why sometimes i got NA?: According to me, NA may appear in the situation when the value of w(equal to min(w)) increases 2 * length(x) where x is a parameter used in the function.